# How do I insert vertical lines when they just don't print out?

Tags: tables, vertical

my question is how do I insert vertical lines when they just don't print out even when they are defined in the code? The question is about the two right vertical lines, which are exactly defined as the the two left ones but aren't printed out in the PDF. Im an using NiceTabular because otherwise the vertical lines would be interrupted by each horizontal line.
One question in addition to the first one: How can I vertically center the cells with the numbers 3,6,8 und 9?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left= 2.5cm,right = 2cm, bottom = 4 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[color={1 0 .5}]{attachfile2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,shadows,calc,matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\newcommand\tabrotate[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}
\newcommand{\frontmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
}
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\slshape \leftmark}
%%
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
%%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\hyphenation{De-zi-mal-tren-nung}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    
    \newpage
    
    %Abkürzungsverzeichnis
    \addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
    \label{sec:abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
    
    \begin{acronym}[LV]

        \acro{LV}{Lösungsvariante}

    \end{acronym}

    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|ccccccc|lllclllllll|l|}
            \toprule
            \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-25.2\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\ac{LV} eintragen}} } 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-22.85\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{ Mit Aufgabenstellung verträglich}}}
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-8\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Forderungen der Anforderungsliste erfüllt}}} 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-1.45\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Grundsätzliche Realisierungschancen gegeben}}} 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-20.65\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Akzeptabler Bearbeitungsaufwand}}} 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-15.55\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Kein Störeinfluss auf das Experiment}}}
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-29\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Im eigenen Bereich bevorzugt}} } &  &                                       &                                   \textbf{Auswahlliste}               & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-57.45\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Entscheidung}}} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &   
            \\
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{p{15em}}{ \rule{0pt}{85pt}Beurteilen der \ac{LV}:} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(+)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Auswahlkriterium erfüllt / \ac{LV} weiter verfolgen}  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(-)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Auswahlkriterium nicht erfüllt / \ac{LV} scheidet aus} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
            \\ 
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(?)}  & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Informationsmangel} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(!)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Anforderungsliste überprüfen  }                   &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
            \\ 
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\rule{0pt}{20pt}Bemerkungen}  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \midrule
            1  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \textbf{+} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \midrule
            2  & + & + & - &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Bauraum der verfügbaren Aktoren ist zu groß} & \textbf{-} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \midrule
            3  & + & + & - &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Die Kraft des Aktors ist für die Festkörpermechanik zu gering} & \textbf{-} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
            \\
            \midrule
            4  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{} & \textbf{+} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &
            \\
            \midrule
            5  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{} & \textbf{+} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &
            \\
            \midrule
            6  & + & + & + & + & - &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Aggregat ist bauraumintensiv bringt Vibrationen in das Experiment} & \textbf{-} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &
            \\
            \midrule
            7  & + & + & - &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Aktorkraft ist zu gering} & \textbf{-} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \midrule
            8  & + & + & (-) & + & (-) & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{  Schrittweite, die ohne überzurutschen gefahren werden kann ist für einen dynamischen Scann zu gering und die Aktorkraft ist gering} & \textbf{-} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \midrule
            9  & + & + & (-) & + & - &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Thermische Aktoren beeinflussen zu stark die Experimentumgebung} & \textbf{-} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\      
            \midrule
            10  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{ } & \textbf{+} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\      
            \midrule
            11  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{} & \textbf{+} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  
            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular*}
        \caption[Auswahlliste]{Auswahlliste um die Vorauswahl der zu präzisierenden Konzepte zu reduzieren}
        \label{tab:Auswahlliste}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Im happy about any hint and thanks in advance.

Comment: please always post complete test documents don't make people guess how to complete a fragment to see the problem, however it isn't clear why yuo have `\multicolumn{1}{p{15em}}` everywhere but that removes the vertical line perhaps you intended `\multicolumn{1}{p{15em}|}` or simpler do not use multicolumn at all and specify `p{15em}` for the tabular column,

Comment: I have edited the question so the code can run. I have added all used usepackages because I don't know if there is some package that has an influence on my problem.

Comment: it is easy for you to check that by removing the packages from example before you post it. (It is hard for anyone else to check anything of the example doesn't run) however the answer is as above that you are removing the lines with the `\multicolumn` specifications

Comment: Why have you defined the 7 left aligned columns after the lone center aligned column? You never used them. If you remove those, you will get the vertical lines as defined. https://imgur.com/uHhLfsH

Comment: Have you both tested it, because when I fix my code as proposed the table is falling apart in both cases?

Comment: But I don't know why I need the seven left columns either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: output]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left= 2.5cm,right = 2cm, bottom = 4 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[color={1 0 .5}]{attachfile2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,shadows,calc,matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\newcommand\tabrotate[1]{\rotatebox{90}{#1\hspace{\tabcolsep}}}
\newcommand{\frontmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
}
\newcommand{\mainmatter}{
    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
%
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{\slshape \leftmark}
%%
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
%%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\hyphenation{De-zi-mal-tren-nung}

\begin{document}

    \pagestyle{fancy}

    
    \newpage
    
    %Abkürzungsverzeichnis
    \addchap{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
    \label{sec:abkuerzungsverzeichnis}
    
    \begin{acronym}[LV]

        \acro{LV}{Lösungsvariante}

    \end{acronym}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|*{7}{c}|*{3}{l}|c|}
            \toprule
            \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-25.2\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{\ac{LV} eintragen}} } 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-22.85\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{ Mit Aufgabenstellung verträglich}}}
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-8\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Forderungen der Anforderungsliste erfüllt}}} 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-1.45\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Grundsätzliche Realisierungschancen gegeben}}} 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-20.65\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Akzeptabler Bearbeitungsaufwand}}} 
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-15.55\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Kein Störeinfluss auf das Experiment}}}
            & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-29\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Im eigenen Bereich bevorzugt}} } &  &                                       &                                   \textbf{Auswahlliste}               & \multirow{7}{*}{\raisebox{-57.45\height }{\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Entscheidung}}}      
            \\
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{p{15em}}{ \rule{0pt}{85pt}Beurteilen der \ac{LV}:} &    
            \\
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(+)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Auswahlkriterium erfüllt / \ac{LV} weiter verfolgen}  &  
            \\
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(-)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Auswahlkriterium nicht erfüllt / \ac{LV} scheidet aus} &     
            \\ 
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(?)}  & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Informationsmangel} &      
            \\
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5em}}{(!)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{13.5em}}{Anforderungsliste überprüfen  }                   &     
            \\ 
            \cmidrule{8-10}
            &  &  &  &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{l}{\rule{0pt}{20pt}Bemerkungen}  &   
            \\
            \midrule
            1  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{l}{} & \textbf{+}    
            \\
            \midrule
            2  & + & + & - &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Bauraum der verfügbaren Aktoren ist zu groß} & \textbf{-}    
            \\
            \midrule
            3  & + & + & - &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{m{21em}}{Die Kraft des Aktors ist für die Festkörpermechanik zu gering} & \textbf{-}    
            \\
            \midrule
            4  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{} & \textbf{+}   
            \\
            \midrule
            5  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{} & \textbf{+}  
            \\
            \midrule
            6  & + & + & + & + & - &  & \multicolumn{3}{m{21em}}{Aggregat ist bauraumintensiv bringt Vibrationen in das Experiment} & \textbf{-}   
            \\
            \midrule
            7  & + & + & - &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{Aktorkraft ist zu gering} & \textbf{-}    
            \\
            \midrule
            8  & + & + & (-) & + & (-) & + & \multicolumn{3}{m{21em}}{  Schrittweite, die ohne überzurutschen gefahren werden kann ist für einen dynamischen Scann zu gering und die Aktorkraft ist gering} & \textbf{-}    
            \\
            \midrule
            9  & + & + & (-) & + & - &  & \multicolumn{3}{m{21em}}{Thermische Aktoren beeinflussen zu stark die Experimentumgebung} & \textbf{-}  
            \\      
            \midrule
            10  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{ } & \textbf{+}    
            \\      
            \midrule
            11  & + & + & + & + & + & + & \multicolumn{3}{p{21em}}{} & \textbf{+}   
            \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular*}
        \caption[Auswahlliste]{Auswahlliste um die Vorauswahl der zu präzisierenden Konzepte zu reduzieren}
        \label{tab:Auswahlliste}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

I have removed all of the last 8 left-aligned columns. And to vertically align the rows mentioned in the question, `m` type column was used instead of `p` type.

Note: You mentioned that you used `nicematrix` for compatibility between `booktabs` and vertical rules. However, there are many other features in this package. For example you may use the `\Block` command instead of `\multirow`. You may take a look at [the package documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf). First 20 pages is enough for your table. Also there are some examples in section 17.

Comment: Thanks alot for the hints and in particular for the complete solution, it works and was very helpful.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You have some mismatch with number of needed, used and specified columns. Also table code is unnecessary complex. Since I'm not very familiar with `nicematrix` that be able to show you how to improved your MWE, I rather suggest to use `tabularray` package. Using it together with `makecell` package, your table's code become much shorter and simpler.

In MWE (Minimal Working Example) is in preamble loaded only for table necessary packages. Between them are three new (indicated by `% <--- new`). BTW, I suggest you in preamble replace code lines

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

with single

```
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
```

which combine and extend `color` and `colortbl` package.

Suggested MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}  % <--- new
\usepackage{makecell}   % <--- new
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\usepackage{tabularray} % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{ Realisierungschancen erfüllt }    % from makecell

\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z}=1pt, hline{2-Y} = {solid}, vlines,
             colspec ={*{9}{l,m} Q[c,m,$]},
             colsep=3pt,
             vspan=evenly
             }  
\SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}     \ac{LV} eintragen
    & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}   Mit Aufgabenstellung verträglich 
        & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}   Forderungen der Anforderungsliste erfüllt
            & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}   Grundsätzliche Realisierungschancen gegeben 
                & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}   Akzeptabler Bearbeitungsaufwand
                    & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}   Kein Störeinfluss auf das Experiment
                        & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell}   Im eigenen Bereich bevorzugt   
                            & \SetCell[c=2]{c} \textbf{Auswahlliste}
                                    &   & \SetCell[r=7]{cmd=\rotcell, font=\normalfont} Entscheidung   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   & \SetCell[c=2]{c}   Beurteilen der \ac{LV}: 
                                    &   & 
                                        \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   (+) &  {Auswahlkriterium erfüllt/\ac{LV}\\ 
                                        weiter verfolgen}    
                                        &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &  (--) &  {Auswahlkriterium nicht erfüllt/ \ac{LV}\\ 
                                        scheidet aus}        
                                        &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   (?) &   Informationsmangel   
                                        &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   (!) &   Anforderungsliste überprüfen 
                                        &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c} Bemerkungen 
                                    &   &   \\
1   & + & + & + & + & + & + &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}
                                    &   & + \\
2   & + & + & --&   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em} 
                                Bauraum der verfügbaren Aktoren ist zu groß
                                    &   & - \\
3   & + & + & --&   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em} 
                                Die Kraft des Aktors ist für die Festkörpermechanik zu gering
                                    &   & - \\
4   & + & + & + & + & + & + &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}
                                    &   & + \\                                
5   & + & + & + & + & + & + &   \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em}
                                    &   & + \\
6   & + & + & + & + & --&   &   \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em}
                                Aggregat ist bauraumintensiv bringt Vibrationen in das Experiment
                                    &   & - \\
7   & + & + & --&   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em}
                                Aktorkraft ist zu gering
                                    &   & - \\
8   & + & + &(--)&+&(--)& + &  \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em}
                             Schrittweite, die ohne überzurutschen gefahren werden kann ist für einen dynamischen Scann zu gering und die Aktorkraft ist gering
                                    &   & - \\
9   & + & + &(--)& + & --&  &  \SetCell[c=2]{j,wd=18em}
                             Thermische Aktoren beeinflussen zu stark die Experimentumgebung
                                    &   & - \\
10  & + & + & + & + & + & + &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}
                                    &   & + \\
11  & + & + & + & + & + & + &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}
                                    &   & + \\
 \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which gives to my opinion nicer and more consistent result as can be obtained with your table code.

[image]

**Note**:
Package `tabularray` is rather new package and similarly as `nicematrix` work well with `booktabs` package (remove interruptions in vertical table lines).

In a cases that in tables written by help of `tabularray` package you like to use rules from `booktabs`, you need to load it as `tabularray` library:

```
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
```

However, many features of `booktabs` are already inherent in `tabularray` code as are vertical distances above/below horizontal lines, simple defining thickness of selected lines etc. Exploiting latter feature, there is no reason to use `booktabs` rules. Consequently they are omitted in the above MWE.

Both packages are still in fast development and both introduce new commands for specifications of table elements. Consequently they require some learning efforts and consulting with packages' documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the hints!!!

Comment: @JoHo, you are welcome. See edited answer. I add more explanation and suggestion to is. BTW, my experience shows that shorter code is usually more clear and less prone to errors.